# Photo Competition 2021-11-29: Sliver

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Sliver

An image that captures only a small part of a much larger whole.

This theme was suggested by [LightBender](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/68136/lightbender).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](//photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126838/photo-competition-2021-11-29-sliver?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on December 20, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: "Sliver (definition) - A long slender piece of something cut or torn off of the whole." It's not just a smaller piece of a whole, it needs to be a long and slender piece as well to fit the category.

Comment: @MichaelC that was the wording of the suggested theme that was highest-voted when it was selected for this contest. The time and place for wordsmithing a theme is at its suggestion post at [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/)

Comment: With the singular title "Sliver", should it not be fairly self-apparent that images should be of "slivers" of  something? The primary word in the theme is "Sliver". How can we know at that stage that a majority of the entrants are going to disregard the title, **Sliver**, as that word is properly defined?

Comment: @MichaelC It is what it is. It's published, we should stick with what we have.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Top of the Tail

[image: Top of the Tail]

The scutes on the top of an crocodile's tail at the Crocodile Lagoon, Cozumel, Mexico, Mar 2, 2019

Nikon D700, Nikkor 80-400 @ 400mm
f9 1/250s ISO 500

Answer (score 19):

**storm grate in snowfall**

A sliver? How about 9?

Taken Dec 2005 in Urbana, IL with a Canon 300D using a Canon 28mm f2.8 lens for 1/160 @f/5 on ISO 100.

[image: storm grate in snowfall]

Comment: That's just grate. I like the smoothness of the snow contrasted with the black of the holes.

Comment: Dad joke FTW!!!

Answer (score 15):

### Gerbera Daisy

[image: Daisy]

Gerbera Daisy, studio
Fujifilm X-H1, XF80mm macro, tripod
1/25 at f/8.0, ISO 400

Answer (score 14):

### Whale's Eye

[image]

Whale replica at [Jyllands Akvariet](https://www.google.com/search?q=jyllands+akvariet+thyboron&tbm=isch), Thyborøn, Denmark.

Nikon D3100, September 2021.

Answer (score 13):

### Perfect Symmetry

Camera : Nikon D5200

Lens : TAMRON 18-400mm F3.5-6.3

Shutter : 1/160

Focal Length : 46.0 mm

Aperture : ƒ/10.0

Taken in Sydney, Australia.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

### Sliver of Home

[image]

Nikon D500 + Sigma 150-600

1/2000, ƒ/5.6, ISO 566

San Francisco, 5 July 2021

Answer (score 11):

### Tip of the Iceberg

[image]

Nikon D500 + Sigma 150-600

1/3200, ƒ/6.3, ISO 224

Seward, Alaska

1 August 2021

Answer (score 10):

**Sliver View**

[image]

A sliver of a view of a couple making out in Central Park in November 2012.

Canon EOS 400D, 24-85mm @ 85mm, f/5.6, 1/125 seconds

Comment: Maybe I’m struggling with angles, but aren’t they just looking at a phone?

Comment: @Tim You know, that might just well be...

Answer (score 10):

**Sun Sliver**

[image]

People walking in a sliver of sunshine in the depths of Manhattan’s “concrete canyon” on Vanderbilt Avenue on a bitterly cold Valentine’s Day in 2016.

Canon EOS 6D, 50mm macro, f/7.1, 1/250 second

Answer (score 5):

### Heart of Nature

[image: Sculpture by Daniel Popper]

FujiFilm X-T3, XF18-135mm @29.3mm
1/125 at f/8.0, ISO 160

Detail of a Daniel Popper sculpture, "Hallow".
On display at Morton Arboretum near Chicago.

Answer (score 2):

#### Camouflage

[image: frog]

Canon 70D + Tamron 17-50mm F2.8

ISO 100 | ƒ/4.5 | 1/80s | 50mm

Dumaguete City, Philippines 2020

Comment: How is this a sliver of anything?

Answer (score 2):

### River Side

[image: Skyline from Chicago River]

Chicago River Lineup
FujiFilm X-E3, XF18-55mm @26.5mm
1/680 at f/5.6, ISO 200

Shot from a balcony across the river. Looking East, W. Randolph to the right.

Answer (score 2):

**The Bus**
[image: Part of bus]

This is a side view of the front part of a bus.

Samsung A5 f/1.9 3.70mm ISO 40

Answer (score 2):

### Shining Shore

[image: shining shore]
Hawke's Bay Beach, Karachi, Pakistan
 November 28, 2021

Redmi Note 7, Xiomi
ISO **160** | *ƒ*/1.8 | 1/95822s | 4.74mm

Amazing view of morning sun shining above waves hitting the sea-shore

Comment: What part of this image is a sliver of anything?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Nikon D3100, Tamron SP 1:8 500mm BBAR MC, f8, 1/2000s, ISO 200, December 2021.